# Plotting probability in R with plants as an example

Tags: r, loops, time, probability

#### Scenario:

I am sampling for plants in a riverine area. Previous studies have suggested that during this time of year, 2% of the samples will be water hyacinth. I realize that I can use the binomial theorem to figure out the probability of sampling m plants in n trials.

I will sample 100 plants today. The sample rate (of all plants) is 500 plants per hour. If I start at 9am and use a loop to show what time will I likely (95%) have collected *at least* 100 plants and be able to go home? I need to store the output of this loop and plot the result as a line graph (time vs probability).
My code below runs for a long time and it does not stop.

#### This is my code so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
hour <- c() 
hours <- 9:00
plantNum <- c()
while(sum(plantNum, na.rm=TRUE) < 100){
plantNum <- c()
plantNum <- rbinom(1, 500, 0.02)
hour <- hour + 1
       
  }
quantile(plantNum, 0.95, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: By you *"will sample 100 plants today"* you mean *hyacinths*, right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way.
You must update `plantNum`, not restart it every time through the loop.
And set a hours limit by testing if it's still less than 24h.

```
set.seed(2021)
hour <- 0L
plantNum <- c()
while((sum(plantNum, na.rm=TRUE) < 100) && hour < 24) {
  plantNum <- c(plantNum, rbinom(1, 500, 0.02))
  hour <- hour + 1L
}
quantile(plantNum, 0.95, na.rm = TRUE)
# 95% 
#15.2
```

---

## Simulation

This code creates a function to simulate the problem's experiment. Then replicates `R = 10000` times the experiment and plots two graphs. None of them is a line graph, that doesn't seem appropriate.

```
sim_plants <- function(size = 500, binprob = 0.02, qprobs = 0.95){
  hour <- 0L
  plantNum <- c()
  while((sum(plantNum, na.rm=TRUE) < 100) && hour < 24) {
    plantNum <- c(plantNum, rbinom(1, size = size, prob = binprob))
    hour <- hour + 1L
  }
  qq <- quantile(plantNum, probs = qprobs, na.rm = TRUE)
  d1 <- data.frame(hour)
  d2 <- as.data.frame(t(qq))
  cbind(d1, d2)
}

set.seed(2021)
R <- 10000L
Plants <- replicate(R, sim_plants(), simplify = FALSE)
Plants <- do.call(rbind, Plants)

hist(Plants$`95%`)
abline(v = mean(Plants$`95%`), col = "red")
```

[image]

```
boxplot(`95%` ~ hour, Plants, type = "l")
```

[image]